# if multiple pieces of state data always change together should i only keep one in state and the rest in class vars?

Tags: reactjs, state

having a hard time understanding exactly what to keep in state for plain React.

say i have a top component `<App>` (holding all state) and a few other display components nested (displaying passed props but have no state)

it seems my app can get on just fine by moving almost all the data to class variables and keeping just a handful in state.

my question is: if multiple pieces of data always change together should i just pick one to keep in state and put the others in class variables since triggering a change in one will re-render the `<App>` component anyway - including the nested components that are displaying class variables?

Answer (score 1):

If you are altering lots of state at once you could store some of the data in instance variables and just use one state, but it would be awfully confusing to read and would be easy to mess up later (for example, to update one class variable and not update the state variable).  You could just as easily store multiple items in state, or store one large object in state and update the properties of that object.

However, if you have lots of different state updates you may want to consider utilizing [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) to manage the state.  From that page:

> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one. useReducer also lets you optimize performance for components that trigger deep updates because you can pass dispatch down instead of callbacks.

One final thought: I would recommend that any piece of data that if updated independently should trigger a re-render, you should probably have that in state.  You never know what might happen in the future, and that could cause some fantastic bugs. :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply. The process of passing data through props is strange to me. Feels like data and handler functions are all jammed in the top parent component (<App>). But I'm still a novice with react hopefully things become more clear

Comment: It's up to you how you organize your code.  Things can be as consolidated or distributed as you like.  It all comes down to which components need what data and how you want to distribute the functionality/responsibility.  Good luck figuring out your style!